# Why does the Oracle JDK Javadoc not include the strict floating point modifier?

Tags: java, javadoc, strictfp

If I look at the `StrictMath.toRadians()` in the NetBeans Javadoc window, the top two lines read

```
java.​lang.​StrictMath
public static strictfp double toRadians(double angdeg)
```

That makes sense, since the JDK I'm using has `StrictMath.toRadians()` defined with the `strictfp` modifier. However, if I look at [the `StrictMath` Javadoc online](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StrictMath.html), I see no mention whatsoever of `strictfp`. The top line of the `toRadians()` Javadoc, for example, reads

```
public static double toRadians(double angdeg)
```

I'm using the JDK 1.8.0_241, the runtime is slightly ahead. Fairly certain it's the Oracle JDK. As far as I can tell, the Javadoc comments in the JDK source for `StrictMath` match what is posted in the Oracle page linked above.

Is it that the Javadoc tool ignores the `strictfp` modifier or is it that Oracle deliberately took it out of the generated `StrictMath` Javadoc HTML pages?

(I tried to generate Javadoc for a dummy `strictfp` function, but it seems I've got a whole bunch of seemingly unrelated Javadoc errors in the project I tried to do that in).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#sthref83) of `javadoc` for Java 8 says:

> The `javadoc` command can include the modifiers `public`, `protected`, `private`, `abstract`, `final`, `static`, `transient`, and `volatile`, but not `synchronized` or `native`. The `synchronized` and `native` modifiers are considered implementation detail and not part of the API specification.

It doesn't explicitly list `strictfp`, but since `strictfp` is a feature that affects the implementation of the method, not how it is used, it is excluded for that reason.

Comment: I would consider `strictfp` part of the specification.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne No more than `synchronized` is not being part of the specification for the out-dated [`Vector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) class, even though the text of the javadoc says *"Vector is synchronized"*. Notice that javadoc of [`StrictMath`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StrictMath.html) doesn't say anything about `strictfp`, it only talks about `fdlibm` and "IEEE 754 core function", so the class could choose to implement all the methods as `native`, in which case `strictfp` wouldn't matter. It's an *implementation* detail!